# Merge sort comparison

Tags: algorithm

I am reading "Analysis of Algorithms" by Sedgewick and Flajolet.In page 7 theoren 1.1 gives:

[image]

And the proof is given below:[image]

Can some one explain this where O(N) goes?Because it proves Cn is O(NlogN).

Comment: Without having done a rigorous analysis, I believe the O(N) term is needed when N≠2^n. In that case, the number of comparisons is C_N+R, where R is the number of the remaining comparisons, which are the difference between N and the next-smaller 2^n, and thus bounded by O(N) (in fact, 0<R<N/2, and thus R∈O(N)).

Comment: It is important to distinguish between exact formulas and there asymptotic bounds. The O(N) has to be stated in the otherwise exact formula "N lg N + O(N)". It can be dropped when only the O(N lg N) bound is stated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math


Comment: It's about the time bound of a very commonly used algorithm, and algorithms are fair game. I think we lose more by closing it than by having answers for it in SO.

Answer (score 3):

You're right; for reasons that are beyond me, they stated more theorem than they actually proved. Here's one way to fill in the rest.

**Lemma** Let T(n) for integers n >= 1 be defined by

```
T(n) = 0,                                for n = 1;
       T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + n, for n > 1.
```

Then T(n) <= n lg n + n - 1 = n lg n + O(n) for integers n >= 1.

**Proof** By induction. For n = 1, T(1) = 0 = 1 lg 1 + 1 - 1. For n > 1, there are two cases. If n is even, then

```
T(n)  = 2T(n/2) + n
     <= 2(n/2) lg(n/2) + 2n/2 - 2 + n
      = n (lg n - 1) + 2n - 2
     <  n lg n + n - 1.
```

If n is odd, then things get complicated.

```
T(n)  = T(n/2 - 1/2) + T(n/2 + 1/2) + n
     <=   (n/2 - 1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2) + (n/2 - 1/2) - 1
        + (n/2 + 1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2) + (n/2 + 1/2) - 1
        + n
      = (n/2 - 1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2) + (n/2 + 1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2) + 2n - 2.
```

The two ugly terms both are close to (n/2) lg(n/2), so we write each as that quantity plus an error term.

```
T(n) <= (n/2 - 1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2) + (n/2 + 1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2) + 2n - 2
      =   (n/2) lg(n/2) + ((n/2 - 1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2) - (n/2) lg(n/2))
        + (n/2) lg(n/2) + ((n/2 + 1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2) - (n/2) lg(n/2))
        + 2n - 2
      =   n lg(n/2) + 2n - 2
        + (n/2 - 1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2) - (n/2) lg(n/2)
        + (n/2 + 1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2) - (n/2) lg(n/2)
      =   n (lg n - 1) + 2n - 2
        + (n/2) (lg(n/2 - 1/2) - lg(n/2)) - (1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2)
        + (n/2) (lg(n/2 + 1/2) - lg(n/2)) + (1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2)
      =   n lg n + n - 2
        + (n/2) lg((n/2 - 1/2)/(n/2)) - (1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2)
        + (n/2) lg((n/2 + 1/2)/(n/2)) + (1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2)
      =   n lg n + n - 2
        + (n/2) lg(1 - 1/n) - (1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2)
        + (n/2) lg(1 + 1/n) + (1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2)
      =   n lg n + n - 2
        + (n/2) lg(1 - 1/n) + (n/2) lg(1 + 1/n)
        + (1/2) lg(n/2 + 1/2) - (1/2) lg(n/2 - 1/2)
      =   n lg n + n - 2
        + (n/2) lg((1 - 1/n) (1 + 1/n))
        + (1/2) lg((n/2 + 1/2) / (n/2 - 1/2))
      =   n lg n + n - 2
        + (n/2) lg(1 - 1/n^2)
        + (1/2) lg(1 + 2/(n - 1)).
```

The term (n/2) lg(1 - 1/n^2) is negative, and, for n >= 3, the minimum n for this case, the term (1/2) lg(1 + 2/(n - 1)) is at most 1/2. (Actually, we could go back and redo the proof to show that T(n) <= n lg n + n/2 - 1/2. I'm going to leave that as an exercise.) Hence,

```
T(n) <    n lg n + n - 2
        + 0
        + 1
      = n lg n + n - 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where the O(N) you're asking about is wrong or missing, but their analysis is fine for the special case `N = 2^n`.

The first line of math after (1) just re-states the recurrence for the special case.  The next, long line of math shows

```
C_{2^n} = (2^n) n
```

Now we know `2^n = N` and so `n = lg N`.  Substituting with both of these we get

```
C_N = N lg N
```

as they say.  If I'm not seeing your question correctly, please comment.